# Retry Axios POST requests with timeout for each retry attempt

Tags: node.js, axios, axios-retry

I have a use case where i need to retry a Axios request  for 3 times in case of any error and each retry attempt should timeout in 3 seconds if it doesnt get any response within 3 seconds.  Below is the code i am using. It retries for 3 times but it doesnt timeout each retry attempt. How can i timeout each retry attempt ? Any code snippets will be helpful.

```
const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry');
axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 });

axios.post(url,payload,{headers:header})
 .then((response) =>{
    console.log('Response is *****'+JSON.stringify(response));

})
.catch((err) =>{
    console.log('Error occurred'+err);

});
```

Answer (score 23):

1) I don't see you setting `timeout` to 3 seconds anywhere in your code.

2) By default, `axios-retry` interprets the request timeout as a global value, so if you need it to timeout after 3 seconds on *each* retry, set `shouldResetTimeout: true`.

3) By default, `axios-retry` does not retry timed out requests (i.e. those with `ECONNABORTED` code) and non-idempotent requests like `POST`. Set a custom `retryCondition` to change that.

Given the above points, something like this should work:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const axiosRetry = require('axios-retry');
axiosRetry(axios, {
  retries: 3,
  shouldResetTimeout: true,
  retryCondition: (_error) => true // retry no matter what
});

axios.post(url, payload, {headers: header, timeout: 3000})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log('Response is *****', res);

  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error occurred' + err);
  });
```

Also, make sure to use `axios@0.19.1` or above.

Comment: thanks for the answer. for me axios retry with .post would not work until I added the line you suggested:  retryCondition: () => true